# How to expand the initializer list parameters pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, parameter-pack

Codes like:

```
template <typename... type>
void print(type... pack) {
    ((std::cout << pack << " "), ...);
}
```

But I have parameters like:
`{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }`

So how can I pass this to the function ?
Or, how to expand the parameters pack like this ?

Comment: I don't think you can unless you change the function parameter to nested initializer_lsit

Comment: Could you please show me how ? :D

Comment: `{1, 2, 3}` has no types, and can only be deduced in limited context (`std::initializer_list<int>` or `T(&)[N]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I have parameters like: { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }

You can pack them into `std::tuple`s

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>

template <typename... Tuples>
void print_tuples(Tuples... tuples) {
  (std::apply([](auto... args) {
    ((std::cout << args << " "), ...);
  }, tuples), ...);
}
```

Then

```
print_tuples(std::tuple{1, 2, 3}, std::tuple{4, 5, 6});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9vaeKEsYh)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to expand all the `initlizer_list` in a row.

```cpp
// for single initializer_list
template <typename T>
void print(std::initializer_list<T> args) {
    for (const auto arg : args) {
        std::cout << arg << " ";
    }
}

// for nested initializer_list
template <typename T>
void print(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> args) {
    for (const auto arg : args) {
        print(arg);
    }
}
```

See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3erT8c5q6)